# Create a Redux-saga listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a UPDATE_DATE action on redux saga.
I want to update multiple resources every time that Date is modified. I would like to implement a listener to action UPDATE_DATE_SUCCESS that triggers a callback. Any idea? I would be great if I can call it from the React component.

Action:
    UPDATE_DATE
    UPDATE_DATE_SUCCESS
    UPDATE_DATE_FAILURE

```
export const {
  updateDate,
  OnDateChange,
} = createActions({
  [ActionTypes.UPDATE_DATE]: (date) => date,
});
```

Saga

```
export function* updateDate(newDate) {
  console.log('from sagas to reducer', newDate); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  try {
    yield put({
      type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_DATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: newDate,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    yield put({
      type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_DATE_FAILURE,
      payload: err,
    });
  }
}

export default function* root() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(ActionTypes.UPDATE_DATE, updateDate),
    takeEvery(ActionTypes.UPDATE_DATE_SUCCESS, test),
  ]);
}
```

Desirable implementation on React Component

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    dispatch(onDateChange((newDate) => {
        dispatch(getApps(newDate));
        dispatch(getPlatforms(newDate));
        dispatch(getNetworks(newDate));
        dispatch(getCountries(newDate));
        dispatch(getFormats(newDate));
        dispatch(getDevices(newDate));
        dispatch(getNetworkKeys(newDate));
    }));
  }
```

Any help? thank you!

Comment: Why not chain multiple `dispatches` in the `saga` on success or failure ?

Comment: because the resources depend on the current view. in order to save non-needed queries, it would be great to just trigger specific queries dynamically.

Comment: While you can magically pass an observer/channel around to achieve this, this is not really a pattern that you should use with sagas. I'd suggest having a saga per section/view each handling its own dispatches. You can either run/stop such saga on mount/unmount of the view or you can run it at the start of your app and have a condition such as (currentSection === thisSection) in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind Redux Sagas is to handle the `side-effects` of an action/event on the Saga rather than in the components.
I think the way of doing that would be something like this (Note the snippet code is not tested, use it as reference/example only):

```js
// --> Saga <-- //
import { getApps, getPlatforms, getNetworks, getCountries, getFormats, getDevices, getNetworkKeys } from './actions.js';

export function* updateDateWatcher(action) {
  const { payload: newDate } = action;
  if (!newDate) return;

  try {
    // dispatch all required actions
    yield all([
      put(getApps(newDate),
      put(getPlatforms(newDate),
      put(getNetworks(newDate)),
      put(getCountries(newDate)),
      put(getFormats(newDate)),
      put(getDevices(newDate)),
      put(getNetworkKeys(newDate)),
    ]);
    // then trigger a success action if you want to
    yield put(updateDataSuccess());
  } catch (err) {
    // if something wrong happens in the try this will trigger 
    yield put(updateDateFailure(err));
  }
}

export default function* root() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(ActionTypes.UPDATE_DATE, updateDateWatcher),
  ]);
}


// --> Component <-- //
import { updateDate } from './actions.js';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onDateChange } = this.props;
    const date = new Date();
    onDateChange(date); // -> triggers ActionTypes.UPDATE_DATE
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onDateChange: (newDate) => dispatch(updateDate(newDate)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: thank you! that worked. And cleaner than what i was hoping for

Comment: Great! happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite understand what you are trying to do but... if you just want a listener, why dont just subscribe a take action that listen for an specific action?

```
 function * mySuperSagaListener() {
    const listener = yield take('some_action_name')
    // calculate the new state here
    // here
    // here
    // when you are done... update the state
    const updateState = yield put({type: 'some_action_name_update', payload: newState})
 }
```

Then you components only will be subscribe of the piece of the state via react-redux HOC... and will update according... and if you want to dispatch actions from the components just:

```
 dispatch({type: 'some_action_name'})
```

Best!